# php - syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, syntax

how i can rid of this error??

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /var/www/core/restvt.api.php on line 35
```

PHP Code :

```
$datax = Array();   
foreach ($inis as $key => $data) {

    if ($data=="mem") {
        $str = number_format($ARRAY[(array_search($data.':',$ARRAY)+2)]/1024,0,',','.')
             . " MB [ ".number_format(($ARRAY[(array_search($data.':',$ARRAY)+2)]/$ARRAY[(array_search($data.':',$ARRAY)+1)])*100,0,',','.')
             . " % ]";
        array_push($datax, "mem"=>$str); //error here, why?
    } else {
        array_push($datax,$data=>$ARRAY[(array_search($data.':',$ARRAY)+1)]);
    }
}

$jsonr = json_encode($datax);
```

thx alot for your help...

Comment: `"mem"=>$str` <--- what's this?

Comment: variable string value from other array, i add for some string into it...

Comment: actually there only brackets missing.... `array_push($datax, ["mem"=>$str])` should do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I **hate** seeing people use array_push - I know it's legal. In this case, you can't **push** a `key => value` to your array, just do this instead:

```
$datax['mem'] = $str;
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

> edit

If you insist on using the `array_push` type method, you'll need to create a new array with your new key value pair then use `array_merge` to join them:

```
$new_data = array('mem' => $str);
$datax = array_merge($datax, $new_data);
```

Answer (score 11):

The error is effectively:

> unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Which means PHP is not expecting those characters `=>`.
You can only use PHP predefined functions as they are intended, which you can find accurate documentation on php.net.
For your function see here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

You are trying to use the function in a way it was not intended, and so PHP throws an error as you performed something PHP does not allow.

So you cannot use the function as you wish, and so need to approach it a different way.
This will work fine - appending a new value (in this case `$str`) to your array:

```
$datax['mem'] = $str;
```

Your array `$datax` now has the new key `mem` with the (new) value of *whatever value is in $str*.
Not only is this method more simple to manage, it has much less overhead as you are not using a function call - `array_push()`.
Visiting the PHP manual page tells you this also.

> If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.